# Round values in data frame separated by comma in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, gridextra

I have a data frame that has values separated by comma or space. How to round these values?

The data frame looks like this:

```
test_type      test_runs       test_values
a              2               0.522,0.433
b              3               1.233,1.455,1.344
```

I want to round the values, output the column without list, and print out the data frame with fixed number of digits using gridextra.

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data.frame(test_type = c("a","a","b","b","b"),
                   test_values = c(0.522,0.433,1.233,1.455,1.344)) %>%
  group_by(test_type) %>%
  summarise(test_runs=n(), test_values=paste(test_values, collapse=","))

round_data <- round(data, digits=2)
```

Comment: Do you have a string column or `list` column for 'test_values` as the `data<-` created is giving error

Comment: Based on the data created, `data$test_values <- lapply(data$test_values, round, 2)`

Comment: I am still trying to find the best way to present my test data. The test_values column will be a string column.

Comment: The best way is to use `dput` i.e. `dput(data)` assuming that you have 2 row example and copy the output into your post

Comment: The data frame now is updated

Comment: Credit to ycw. It works if mutate(test_values = unlist(test_values)) is added. Anyone has other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

A solution from `tidyverse`. `dt2` is the final output.

```
# Create example data frame
dt <- read.table(text = "test_type      test_runs       test_values
                 a              2               0.522,0.433
                 b              3               1.233,1.455,1.344",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Load package
library(tidyverse)

# Process the data
dt2 <- dt %>%
  mutate(test_values = strsplit(test_values, split = ",")) %>%
  mutate(test_values = map(test_values, as.numeric)) %>%
  mutate(test_values = map(test_values, formatC, format = "f", digits = 2)) %>%
  mutate(test_values = map_chr(test_values, paste, collapse = ","))
```

Comment: What is the role of tidyverse library here?

Comment: Your solution actually also converts the chr column to list column, which causes problem when print using gridextra

Comment: `tidyverse` is for functions from `dplyr` and `purrr`.

Comment: And because you did not provide your desired output, I can only work on what I think could be useful. Please provide your desired output.

Comment: I did not see any desired outputs from your updates.

Comment: I have changed the last `map` call to `map_chr` to convert the `test_values` column to character.